# Async SQL Bulk Copy and Batch Selects

Tags: .net, sql-server

The following code is not working (throwing "fatal errors on reader.NextResult()")

My goal is to perform a batch select and then to insert data of each result set async via bulk copy.

I think the problem is that on `reader.NextResult()` the current result set is released from memory but since the async bulk operation is using it, it throws a fatal error (InvalidOperationException). Any ideas?

```
                    var sqlQuery = new DbExtensions.SqlBuilder();
                    foreach (var table in tableBatch)
                    {
                        sqlQuery
                            .SELECT("*")
                            .FROM("[" + table.TableName + "]");
                    }

                    var selectCmd = sqlQuery.ToCommand(clientDb);

                    logger.Info("Executing select", batchSelectSize);
                    var reader = selectCmd.ExecuteReader();

                    var i = 0;
                    while (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        logger.Info("Bulk insert");
                        var table = tableBatch.ElementAt(i);
                        var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(serverDb, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, tx);
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = String.Format("[{0}]", table.TableName);
                        bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = table.EnableStreaming;                            
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(reader);

                        i++;

                        reader.NextResult(); // fatal error occures (sometimes)
                    }

                    logger.Info("Waiting for bulk operations to complete");
                    Task.WaitAll();

                    logger.Info("Committing transaction");
                    tx.Commit();
```

Comment: You are using ADO.NET objects concurrently. This is never allowed.

Comment: @usr actually, that's not *quite* true; if you have MARS enabled, the async methods do allow pipelining of multiple operations on a single connection.

Comment: @MarcGravell but are you allowed to start operations and read results in parallel? I doubt it. Only one thread can ever call into the same ADO.NET objects at a time, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you didn't `await` the result; you moved forward too soon. That should be:

```
await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(reader);
```

or

```
await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(reader).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Note also that `Task.WaitAll()` does nothing useful; you are saying "now wait for all zero of these tasks to complete".

Note also that if you're going `async`, you might as well go `async` throughout:

```
var reader = await selectCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
...
await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(reader);
...
await reader.NextResultAsync();
```

(again, perhaps with `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on each, if desired)

Comment: do we have option to do ASYNC for this - ObjectReader.Create? When I try to WriteToServerAsync(reader), it won't write in database. Any thoughts why it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You must delay `NextResult` until you are sure that `WriteToServerAsync` has finished its work. The simplest way to do this correctly is to make the containing method an `async` method, and to `await` `WriteToServerAsync`, like so:

```
await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(reader);
```

For more information about `async` and `await`, please see [async/await tutorials like this one from dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/async) and/or [Microsoft's own documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Comment: I am using a while loop to enumerate all result sets in a reader (batch select).